# How do you enter into fastboot mode for Allwinner A10 tablets (ICS)?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, fastboot

Does anyone know how to enter into fastboot mode for allwinner a10 tablets which are running ICS?

```
adb reboot fastboot
```

only seems to reboot it normally.

Is there a key combination which will take it to fastboot?

Comment: Ok i just found out how,but i'm unable to answer my question so soon...so will update it soon

Comment: Type the following command in your shell

    $ adb shell "echo -n boot-fastboot | busybox dd of=/dev/block/nand<X> count=1 conv=sync; sync; reboot"

please replace <X> with the letter in which your "misc" partition exists.

I think you can find this out by typing 

    $ df

That should take you into fastboot

    $ fastboot devices

should list down your device!

Comment: +1 vote as this is very useful information, I have no idea why it was closed as off-topic, since fastboot is a key tool in developing and then deploying custom versions of Android on real hardware devices.

Comment: E:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb reboot bootloader